# How can I improve the performance of Wrap Widget with multiple child?

Tags: performance, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When I move from tabs in the UI it's takes too long to load the chips under the tabs.
I've used the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<> but it broke my Scrollbar and still takes time to load large Chips children from the Wrap Widget. What I would need is a Wrap.builder() but doesn't exist. Is there something I can do to optimize the code to load smoothly?

I have an interactive sample code of the current problem:
https://dartpad.dev/009e9ccae07175074cb77d7792c3692b

Try moving the tabs left to right in the sample to see the performance issue.
If it can't be fixed, I wonder if I can detect when the widget is rendering to show a circular progress indicator while switching tabs.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Technically the idea of `Wrap.builder` wouldn't be a solution here because the issue persists even when all the items are in the displayed (nothing to display on demand)

You can make the swiping experience better by delaying the rendering of the tab content until after the swiping animation is done

[image]

```
class _ChipsContentState extends State<ChipsContent> {
  bool visible = false;
  final List<String> _filters = <String>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(kTabScrollDuration).then((value) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() => visible = true);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!visible) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    return ListView(
      children: [
        if (visible)
          Wrap(
            spacing: 8.0,
            children: widget.chipData.map((chipName) => ChipFilter(chipName: chipName, filter: _filters)).toList(),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Wrap.builder()` is indeed missing from Flutter. A [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56980) was opened about this but then closed without a satisfying solution.

I can think of a few workarounds, like using a [swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)/carousel, a `GridView.builder()`, or a `List.builder()` with `Rows` inside it. Of course, they're far from being as convenient as a `Wrap` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your `filterChips` and "build" methods as follows,

```
List<Widget> get filterChips {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (final chipName in widget.chipData) {
       widgets.add(ChipFilter(chipName: chipName, filter: _filters));
    }
    return widgets;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // super.build(context);
    return Scrollbar(
           child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Wrap(//IS THERE A Wrap.builder()? OR ALTERNATIVE TO DESIRED LAYOUT?
            spacing: 8.0,
            children: filterChips,
          ),),
    );
```

}